# Configuring Rails Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a rails application and it has a controller named 'mastertest'

By default when I run the application and go to localhost:3000, i would want to redirect to localhost:3000/mastertest.

Can someone help me configure the routes.rb file

Comment: This question would have been easily answered by googling. Please make some effort on you own before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) delete the public/index.html file

2) update your routes file - read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root

Answer (score 2):

Please search a bit ...
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

```
root :to => 'pages#main'
```